# Grep for consecutive words with capital letters

Tags: ubuntu, regular-expression

I am trying to find two consecutive words that start with capital letters.

Example

Input: `x Yyy Zzz xx y`

Output: `Yyy Zzz`

Right now I'm able to find all the capital letters `cat txtfile.txt | grep -o '\<[A-Z][a-z]*\>'`

How to alter the code so I can get the output?

Kind regards

Comment: Are you trying to `grep` entire lines? Or just consecutive capitalized words? Your sole example would suggest the latter. Also, do you need word pairs returned, or all consecutive capitalized words (2 words, 3 words, etc.) returned, whatever number in a row?

Answer (score 2):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne 'my @a = .words.rotor(2 => -1); for @a {.put if $_ ~~ $_.map(*.wordcase)};'
```

Sample Input:

```
x Yyy Zzz xx y
x Yyy Zzz Www
a Mmm: Yyy bbb
aaa aaa aaa
Ccc ccc CCC
Bbb Bbb Bbb Bbb
```

Sample Output:

```
Yyy Zzz
Yyy Zzz
Zzz Www
Mmm: Yyy
Bbb Bbb
Bbb Bbb
Bbb Bbb
```

Calling `.words` instructs Raku to split input lines on whitespace. These words are taken and `rotor`-ed together. The `rotor` parameter `(2 => -1)` instructs words to be taken as adjacent pairs with an overlap such that each consecutive overlapping pair of words is created.

Word pairs are loaded into the `$_` topic variable, and tested to see if they match against `$_.map(*.wordcase)`, in other words, tested to see if they match a version of themselves wherein each word is (initial letter) capitalized. If a match is found then `$_` must be pairs of (initial letter) capitalized words already, and such word pairs are returned.

Note, if a linewise return is required the `.put` call can be replaced by (for example) `print "$_, "`. Also Raku has a `unique` routine if only unique word pairs are desired.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/wordcase
https://docs.raku.org/routine/rotor
https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
cat txtfile.txt | grep -o '[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how it would look if the first word can't be the first word of a sentence? So you find two consecutive words with capital letters from the second word in a sentence and forward?

Comment: @AndersBegtorp, if I understood your question correctly (and you don't mind using grep 2x) you can use: `cat txtfile.txt | grep -v '^[A-Z][a-z]' | grep -o '[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*'`
If you meant on: grep shouldn't match line that starts with word starting with capital letter.
If you meant on: grep shouldn't match line that starts with two consecutive words starting with capitals:
`cat txtfile.txt | grep -v '^[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*' | grep -o '[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*`

Comment: @AndersBegtorp Welcome, if you have other requirements [edit] the question adding them, don't do it in comments. Also add aclarations about Quasimodo's alternative examples.

Comment: @Damir
This doesn't quite work take the string `Edge CaSe` or `I Started` and apply your solution to them...

Comment: @JPI93, thanks, I know, but saw that others gave good examples so I didn't continue fixing my own. It's the same with `EDge Case or EdGe Case`, or... :). It would be great that OPs in general put more details, or their 'Inputs' with more different lines (more different cases)... However, thanks, I will improve my answer soon...

Comment: No worries. Yeah, I think specificity on edge cases and gotchas is pretty important when dealing with regular expressions in general - there are so many of them!

Answer (score 1):

Taking Quasimodo's examples and other possible cases, and assuming punctuations must match, and also more than two consecutive words capitalized, using GNU `grep`:

```bsh
$ cat file
x Yyy Zzz xx y
x Yyy Zzz Www
a Mmm: Yyy bbb
aaa aaa aaa
Ccc ccc CCC
Bbb Bbb Bbb Bbb
```

```
$ grep -P '[A-Z][^ ]*(?: +[A-Z][^ ]*)+' file
x Yyy Zzz xx y
x Yyy Zzz Www
a Mmm: Yyy bbb
Bbb Bbb Bbb Bbb
```

---

- `[A-Z][^ ]*` matches words capitalized followed by any character that is not a space.
- `(?: +[A-Z][^ ]*)+` matches one or more spaces followed by the mentioned pattern repeated once or more times.

---

As suggested by @cas there's this alternative:

Using `-z` will detect sequential capitalised words even across line boundaries (e.g. `CCC\nBbb`). and using `\s` instead of just space will make it work with tabs and other whitespace too.

```
grep -z -P '[A-Z][^\s]*(?:\s+[A-Z][^\s]*)+' file
```